# What method is a delegate assigned to

Tags: c#, delegates

This is the definitions I have in the

```
private SavePreferenceCallback savePreferenceHandler;

public SavePreferenceCallback SavePreferenceHandler
{
  get
  {
    return savePreferenceHandler;
  }
  set
  {
    savePreferenceHandler = value;
  }
}
```

and then in debugging the code when I come to a line that is this:

```
savePreferenceHandler();
```

I don't know how to go further and what to look at? what method is it running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know what method will be called you can mouse over the variable `savePreferenceHandler`, and the debugger will show you what method is assigned.

[image]

You also can put a breakpoint in your property setter to see what method is assigned.

Lastly, you could use <kbd>F11</kbd> and step into the method as it is invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the picture. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>F11</kbd> to step into the code and you'll find out, basically. Or you could always examine the value of `savePreferenceHandler` to see the method (or methods) it represents.

Side-node: if you're using C# 3 or above, you can make that property considerably simpler:

```
public SavePreferenceCallBack SavePreferenceHandler { get; set; }
```

You might also consider making it an *event* instead.

Comment: F12 is 'go to definition', would only show the OP where he declared the `savePreferenceHandler` variable.